# Sintaxe do typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, sintaxe, typedef

Qual é a diferença entre escrever `typedef struct "nome1"{}"NOME2";`, como implementado em uma lista encadeada; e `typedef struct{}"NOME1";`, como implementado em lista sequencial que eu vi.

Também já me deparei com `struct "nome1"{}typedef struct "nome1" "nome2";`. Existe algum padrão sobre escrever o nome em caixa alta?

Lista sequencial:

```
typedef struct{
  char nome[30];
  char posicao[30];
  int  nrCamisa;
}JOGADOR;

typedef struct{
  JOGADOR vetor[MAX];
  int NroElem;
}ELENCO;
```

Lista simplesmente encadeada:

```
typedef struct{
  char nome[30];
  char posicao[30];
  int  nrCamisa;
}JOGADOR;

typedef struct no{
  JOGADOR info;
  struct no* prox;
}ELENCO;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`typedef` cria um tipo novo, ele não tem nada a ver com a estrutura. Você pode fazer assim:

```
typedef int Inteiro
```

Está criando um tipo novo chamado `Inteiro` que será baseado no tipo `int`.

Então pode fazer também:

```
struct exemplo {
    int x;
}

typedef struct exemplo Exemplo;
```

Que é o mesmo que fazer:

```
typedef struct exemplo {
    int x;
} Exemplo;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Typedef.c).

Então aí `exemplo` é o nome da estrutura, e `Exemplo` é o nome do tipo.

Note que eu prefiro usar nomes de tipos começando com maiúsculo ou CamelCase. Há quem goste que de ALL CAPS, há quem goste de tudo minúsculo, não há um padrão universal.

Uma estrutura não precisa ter um nome. Claro que se ela não tiver nome ou só poderá ser usada uma vez ou terá que ser definida em um `typedef` que aí passará ser usado para criar um dado baseada na estrutura anônima.

Particularmente não sou fã de dar nome para a estrutura em um `typedef`. A não ser que tenha o próprio tipo seja usado dentro da estrutura, aí cria um problema, porque o tipo não pode ser usado em uma estrutura que o define, o tipo ainda não existe quando a estrutura está sendo definida. Então no último exemplo tem o nome por causa disto. A estrutura referencia ela mesma antes de definir `ELENCO`, então este nome não pode ser usado, precisa usar o `struct no`.

Note que o nome da estrutura só existe no escopo de uma `struct` enquanto que o nome do tipo é global.