# Usar o typedef anônimo ou não?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

Eu estava vendo alguns códigos em C e me deparei com algo parecido com isto:

*Exemplo:*

```
typedef struct
{
    char nome[256];
} Pessoa;
```

```
typedef struct Pessoa
{
    char nome[256];
} Pessoa;
```

- Tem alguma diferença entre esses dois exemplos?
- Se sim, quais?

Eu sei que no 1º exemplo a `struct` é anônima porque não tem nome, mas só isso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, vamos pular [a parte que já sabe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/230364/101) ([ou isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364771/101)).

É só isso mesmo, a estrutura é anônima e portanto não pode usá-la de forma direta em algum lugar que a exija.

Não sei se sabe mas é possível declarar o tipo de uma variável (local ou não) ou retorno de função assim:

```
struct Pessoa x;
```

Ou pode fazer assim:

```
struct { char nome[256]; } x;
```

Obviamente que essa forma você não pode aproveitar essa definição em outros lugares, fazendo que o código seja menos [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/101) e isso pode ser um problema.

E a forma anônima não permite você dizer qual é a estrutura que quer usar naquele tipo, então também não pode aproveitar. Isto só é possível porque tem um nome:

```
struct Pessoa {
    char nome[256];
};
typedef Pessoa Pessoa;
```

A forma com `typedef` resolve isso porque a estrutura é usada de forma indireta e o tipo é nominado de alguma outra forma:

```
Pessoa x;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Anonymous.c).

Em geral onde dá para definir um tipo próprio (tem caso que pode haver problema de ciclo de definição) não faz muito sentido definir um nome para a `struct`.

Porém há um grupo grande de pessoas que acham que deve definir ambos, assim como existem pessoas que acham que deve escrever código C como se fossem rodar em compiladores dos anos 70 ou 80. Eu discordo deles para quase todos os códigos, e discordo mais nesse caso porque nunca vi uma justificativa plausível para adotar esse padrão. Pode existir. Eu prefiro nomear a estrutura só quando isso é necessário (raro). Há um grupo que defende que nem o `typedef` seja usado, entendo o porquê mas discordo na maioria dos casos.

Existe uma diferença sobre o *namespace* que cada identificador está presente. Com o `typedef` o nome é global, já com a estrutura direta o nome só existe no contexto em que se usa a palavra chave `struct`, e só por isso que ambas podem ter o mesmo nome sendo definições diferentes.

Minha convenção é usar maiúsculo para nomes de tipos, deixando o minúsculo para variáveis.

É mais questão de estilo, cada um dando sua justificativa para usar uma ou outra, mas muda nada tecnicamente. Há quem não goste muito de abstrações ou coisas implícitas.

[No Quora eu respondi algo que dá um exemplo diferente](https://pt.quora.com/Posso-usar-uma-struct-dentro-da-outra-em-C/answer/Antonio-Maniero). [Outra de lá](https://pt.quora.com/Em-linguagem-C-quais-as-diferen%C3%A7as-entre-uma-typedef-struct-e-uma-struct-identificador/answer/Antonio-Maniero).